# Refresh/Reload an aura component

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, aura

I'm trying to reload/refresh the complete aura component for some actions like after hit the submit button in component.

Currently i'm refreshing the complete page by using `location.reload();` . Suggest me is there any better option to reload the custom aura component based on some action.

Comment: Please explain your use case more. From what I could understand I think you can make use of the force:refreshView event. Reference : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:refreshView/documentation

Answer (score 0):

There are few things you can do without using `location.reload` if you just want to fetch the data back from server.

1. You can fetch the data from server again and update the UI after `submit` operation is success.
2. You can recall `doInit` method, so if your `doInit` is fetching the data again it would do the same.

For eg:

If you are calling server side from `init`

```
({
    init: function (cmp, event, helper) {
        helper.fetchDataFromServer(cmp, event, helper);
    },
});
```

---

```
({
    fetchDataFromServer : function (cmp, event, helper) {
        let findContacts = cmp.get('c.fetchContact');
        findContacts.setCallback(this, function (response) {
            // Your action
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(findContacts);
    }
});
```

Then in `handleSubmit` method just recall server again.

```
    handleSubmit: function (cmp, event, helper) {
        // Do your stuff
        helper.fetchDataFromServer(cmp, event, helper);
    }
```